# Why does Altium Designer not detect the GND node?

Tags: schematics, altium

I'm trying to set up a project simulation in Altium Designer.
I have some circuits across two sheets:

[image: First Sheet]

[image: Second Sheet]

As you can see, I included a separate analog and digital ground. I connected them in order to perform a simulation of the circuit using the Mixed Simulation Toolbox.

Whenever I try to start the simulation i get this message:

[image: Error message]

What am I doing wrong? The GND node is in the schematic (both schematics actually) and all the components have models.

The voltage generators are simulation-only components.

I manually created some SUBCKT models for the connectors that have no internal connections.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try making all of your grounds 'SGND'.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I'd like to keep the analog and digital grounds separate. The two nets should however be connected (see schematic). The GND node is connected to those nodes as well.

Comment: You're working with a persnickety simulator.  You'll likely have to do things "its" way.  If you're still having trouble, or would like to voice your displeasure with your multi-kilobucks-software, then try the official Altium forum.  Lots of good people there.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Ahahaha, alright thanks, I will go voice my displeasure there. Luckily as a student I don't pay a single kilobuck.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use a single ground - this is true for real circuits as well.  Multiple grounds will tend to cause more harm than good.   But, getting back to Altium.  Use a single ground or try placing a net label called 0 (on the wire tying the two grounds together).  This is what the SPICE simulator is looking for.  If that isn't working then stick a 1m (milliohm) resistor between the two grounds.